# Vuforia Real time Augmented Reality

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am new to unity and vuforia, I would like to know is it possible that instead of using a image target in vuforia, can I do something like augmenting real time hand drawn illustration? For instance, when I start to draw something on the AR app, then a 3D object representing the object I am drawing would also appear?

Answer (score 0):

Vuforia can recognize pre-defined images, with enough features to be detected. If you draw by hand such an image, that's fine. Otherwise - the answer is no. Just an FYI - Vuforia also has text recognition, if you'd like, take a look here: [Vuforia's Text Recognition](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Text-Recognition-Guide)

Of course that if a detection was made, what happens and what is drawn is up to you, so of course a 3D object is an option.